# How to select max date from a list of max date subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I need to get the MAX date from a bunch of different dates across different tables.  I have a query that returns me 6 dates.  I need to somehow get that max of that query.  Here is my first query that works and gives me the 6 different MAX dates:

```
    SELECT  
        MAX(mi.last_updated_dts),
        (SELECT MAX(lt.created_dts) FROM live_training as lt WHERE lt.me_id = 1156),
        (SELECT MAX(gm.created_dts) FROM group_member as gm WHERE gm.me_id = 1156),
        (SELECT MAX(clm.created_dts) FROM contact_list_member as clm WHERE clm.me_id = 1156),
        (SELECT MAX(mc.created_dts) FROM member_case as mc WHERE mc.me_id = 1156),
        (SELECT MAX(mcc.created_dts) FROM member_case_comment as mcc INNER JOIN member_case as mc ON (mcc.member_case_id = mc.id) WHERE mc.me_id = 1156)
    FROM 
        member_info AS mi
    WHERE mi.id = 1276
```

Here is kind of what I'm trying to do but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT MAX(
             SELECT  
                  MAX(mi.last_updated_dts),
                  (SELECT MAX(lt.created_dts) FROM live_training as lt WHERE lt.me_id = 1156),
                  (SELECT MAX(gm.created_dts) FROM group_member as gm WHERE gm.me_id = 1156),
                  (SELECT MAX(clm.created_dts) FROM contact_list_member as clm WHERE clm.me_id = 1156),
                  (SELECT MAX(mc.created_dts) FROM member_case as mc WHERE mc.me_id = 1156),
                  (SELECT MAX(mcc.created_dts) FROM member_case_comment as mcc INNER JOIN member_case as mc ON (mcc.member_case_id = mc.id) WHERE mc.me_id =1156)
             FROM 
                  member_info AS mi
             WHERE mi.id = 1276
          ) as theMostMaxDate
```

I don't know what to put in the from statement or if this is even possible. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could be to rewrite the query to use `union all` in a derived table and get the max from that, although this would only get you a date and no information about the source of it (but if that is important you could add a column with a literal value indicating what query gave you the max date):

```
SELECT MAX(max_date) 
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(mi.last_updated_dts) AS max_date FROM member_info AS mi WHERE mi.id = 1276
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MAX(lt.created_dts) FROM live_training as lt WHERE lt.me_id = 1156
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MAX(gm.created_dts) FROM group_member as gm WHERE gm.me_id = 1156
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MAX(clm.created_dts) FROM contact_list_member as clm WHERE clm.me_id = 1156
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MAX(mc.created_dts) FROM member_case as mc WHERE mc.me_id = 1156
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MAX(mcc.created_dts) FROM member_case_comment as mcc 
    INNER JOIN member_case as mc ON (mcc.member_case_id = mc.id) WHERE mc.me_id = 1156
) t
```

Comment: @tylerBrignone It would be better to ask a new question instead of adding to the current as the new question would get more exposure plus changing an existing question kind of invalidates the answers (in some sense). I'd be happy to look at a follow up.

Answer (score 0):

Max() is a group by function and works on a single field or expression. Use [greates()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) function instead, that works across multiple fields or expressions.

```
SELECT  
    GREATEST(MAX(mi.last_updated_dts),
    (SELECT MAX(lt.created_dts) FROM live_training as lt WHERE lt.me_id = 1156),
    (SELECT MAX(gm.created_dts) FROM group_member as gm WHERE gm.me_id = 1156),
    (SELECT MAX(clm.created_dts) FROM contact_list_member as clm WHERE clm.me_id = 1156),
    (SELECT MAX(mc.created_dts) FROM member_case as mc WHERE mc.me_id = 1156),
    (SELECT MAX(mcc.created_dts) FROM member_case_comment as mcc INNER JOIN member_case as mc ON (mcc.member_case_id = mc.id) WHERE mc.me_id = 1156)) as maxdate
FROM 
    member_info AS mi
WHERE mi.id = 1276
```

Another solution is to combine the independent queries with union and you can use max() to select the overall maximum from the resultset.

Answer (score 0):

@jpw has the right solution for this problem.  I just want to point out that you can do it without subqueries:

```
SELECT MAX(mi.last_updated_dts) AS max_date FROM member_info AS mi WHERE mi.id = 1276
UNION ALL
SELECT MAX(lt.created_dts) FROM live_training as lt WHERE lt.me_id = 1156
UNION ALL
SELECT MAX(gm.created_dts) FROM group_member as gm WHERE gm.me_id = 1156
UNION ALL
SELECT MAX(clm.created_dts) FROM contact_list_member as clm WHERE clm.me_id = 1156
UNION ALL
SELECT MAX(mc.created_dts) FROM member_case as mc WHERE mc.me_id = 1156
UNION ALL
SELECT MAX(mcc.created_dts) FROM member_case_comment as mcc 
INNER JOIN member_case as mc ON (mcc.member_case_id = mc.id) WHERE mc.me_id = 1156
ORDER BY max_date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```